# How to resolve this deep learning training error of CUDA？

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model

During the early stages of network training, the progress bar is functioning as expected. However, towards the end of the training process, an error suddenly occurs.How can I solve it？
main：

```
            n_o = torch.cuda.IntTensor(n_o)
            p = torch.cuda.FloatTensor(p)
            o = o.cuda()
            o = o.to(torch.int32)
            o = torch.cuda.IntTensor(o)
            p = p.contiguous()
            # o = o.contiguous()
            # n_o = n_o.contiguous()
            idx = pointops.farthest_point_sampling(p, o, n_o)  # (m)
            n_p = p[idx.long(), :]  # (m, 3)
            x, _ = pointops.knn_query_and_group(x, p, offset=o, new_xyz=n_p, new_offset=n_o,
                                                nsample=self.nsample, with_xyz=True)
```

FarthestPointSampling：

```
class FarthestPointSampling(Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, xyz, offset, new_offset):
        """
        input: coords: (n, 3), offset: (b), new_offset: (b)
        output: idx: (m)
        """
        assert xyz.is_contiguous()
        n, b, n_max = xyz.shape[0], offset.shape[0], offset[0]
        for i in range(1, b):
            n_max = max(offset[i] - offset[i - 1], n_max)
        idx = torch.cuda.IntTensor(new_offset[b - 1].item()).zero_()
        tmp = torch.cuda.FloatTensor(n).fill_(1e10)
        farthest_point_sampling_cuda(b, n_max, xyz, offset.int(), new_offset.int(), tmp, idx)
        del tmp
        return idx
```

Error：

```
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1659484810403/work/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/IndexKernel.cu:91: operator(): block: [3,0,0], thread: [126,0,0] Assertion `index >= -sizes[i] && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed.
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1659484810403/work/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/IndexKernel.cu:91: operator(): block: [3,0,0], thread: [127,0,0] Assertion `index >= -sizes[i] && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed.
Epoch 1/2: 100%|████████████████████▉| 6072/6073 [04:14<00:00, 23.85it/s, Loss=1.61, Accuracy=0.253]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/c/Documents/dataparser/HAR/train.py", line 47, in <module>
    outputs = model(inputs)
  File "/home/c/anaconda3/envs/p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/Documents/dataparser/HAR/point_transformer.py", line 184, in forward
    p2, x2, o2 = self.enc2([p1, x1, o1])
  File "/home/c/anaconda3/envs/p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/anaconda3/envs/p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 139, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/home/c/anaconda3/envs/p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/Documents/dataparser/HAR/point_transformer_seg.py", line 93, in forward
    x, _ = pointops.knn_query_and_group(x, p, offset=o, new_xyz=n_p, new_offset=n_o,
  File "/home/c/Documents/dataparser/HAR//pointops/utils.py", line 17, in knn_query_and_group
    return grouping(idx, feat, xyz, new_xyz, with_xyz), idx
  File "/home/c/Documents/dataparser/HAR/pointops/grouping.py", line 45, in grouping
    xyz = torch.cat([xyz, torch.zeros([1, 3]).to(xyz.device)], dim=0)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

Initially, there was another error that would halt at `assert xyz.is_contiguous()`.

```
Epoch 1/2:   0%|                                                           | 0/6073 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/c/Documents/dataparser/train.py", line 47, in <module>
    outputs = model(inputs)
  File "/home/c/anaconda3/envs/p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/Documents/dataparser/transformer.py", line 184, in forward
    p2, x2, o2 = self.enc2([p1, x1, o1])
  File "/home/c/anaconda3/envs/p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/anaconda3/envs/p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 139, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/home/c/anaconda3/envs/p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/Documents/dataparser/HAR/transformer_seg.py", line 91, in forward
    idx = pointops.farthest_point_sampling(p, o, n_o)  # (m)
  File "/home/c/Documents/dataparser/HAR/sampling.py", line 14, in forward
    assert xyz.is_contiguous()
AssertionError
```

Then, I added a piece of code to the preceding program.

```
            p = torch.cuda.FloatTensor(p)
            o = o.cuda()
            o = o.to(torch.int32)
            o = torch.cuda.IntTensor(o)
            p = p.contiguous()
```

Then it can run normally until it encounters the error mentioned above.